# Вывод из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, у меня стоит такой скрипт:

```
     <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_GET[id]'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
   echo "Выводим здесь что хотим";
    }
}

?>
```

Мне надо сделать, чтоб если не чего не вывело высвечивало ошибку **echo "Пусто";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте перед циклом while проверку на количество строк в результате

```
if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
    echo "Пусто";
```

Comment: Не работает

`     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_GET[id]'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
   if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
    echo "Пусто";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата `

Comment: Добавил выше

Comment: Странно, должно работать. А попробуйте вместо моего фрагмента вставить просто echo mysql_num_rows($result); и посмотрите что будет выводить

Comment: Это как? 

`  if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
   echo mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "Пусто";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата `

Вот что высвечивает: http://prntscr.com/38bwgb
А что обозначает 1?

Comment: А вы случайно хотя бы минимальное представление о программировании имеете? Слишком глупый вопрос задаете просто. 1 обозначает кол-во строк, возвращенных из БД

Comment: Вы меня окончательно запутали, попробуйте, если хотите, более внятно обьяснить что вы хотите получить на выходе и что у вас есть в исходных данных, поможем.

Comment: При вставке это скрипта выдает ошибку: 

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a5838895/public_html/index.php on line 73

В этой строке находиться:

` while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { `

Comment: @cnofss Если взялись за программирование -- начинайте уже читать документацию. Там все примеры есть: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2):

Псевдокод такой:

```
$row = fetch;
if(!$row) Пусто;
do {
 Выводим, что хотим;
} while ($row = fetch);
```

На примере Вашего кода:

```
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_GET[id]'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     if(!$row) echo "Пусто";
     do {
        echo "Выводим здесь что хотим";    
     } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
   }
```

Разумеется, вариант [[@MDJHD](/users/16739/mdjhd)](/users/16739/mdjhd) с `mysql_num_rows`, предпочтительнее

Также хочу обратить Ваше внимание на:

- Вы используете устаревшие функции mysql_*, обратите внимание на mysqli_ или PDO
- Ваш код открыт для SQL иньекций: `id='$_GET[id]'`

Comment: скорее перевести, вы в курсе, что такое псевдокод?

Comment: Печально... написал

Comment: Мне кажется, что у Вас нифига не пустой результат)

Comment: Не показывает :c

Из mysql http://prntscr.com/38bxa3
С страницы http://prntscr.com/38bxch

Comment: Напишите `print_r($row)` внутри цикла

Comment: Какого именно? А точнее лучше напишите сюда отрывок от кода

Comment: Кажется я начал догонять, чего вы хотите :) Вам нужно вместо пустых колонок в таблице вывести слово Пусто, да?

Comment: Конечно) Вы правы)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

В примерах всё есть.

Comment: У меня на другом сайте стоит этот скрипт который мне порекомендовал @Alexander Deider и там все норм, а на котором я щас создаю выдает ошибку. Хостинг одинаковый.